# How do I turn this expression into a lambda expression?

Tags: java, lambda

I'd like to turn what I'm doing into lambda, in which case it would be I scroll through a list (listRegistrationTypeWork) within the other, check if the child list (getRegistrationTypeWorkAuthors) is != null, if it is, scroll through it looking for an authorCoautor = type, and increment a count, to find out how many records within the lists have this same type.

```java
public int qtyMaximumWorksByAuthorCoauthor(AuthorCoauthor type) {
    int count = 0;
    for (RegistrationTypeWork tab : listRegistrationTypeWork) {
        if (CollectionUtils.isNotEmpty(tab.getRegistrationTypeWorkAuthors())) {
            for (RegistrationTypeWorkAuthors author : tab.getRegistrationTypeWorkAuthors()) {
                if (author.getAuthorCoauthor().equals(type))
                    count++;
            }
        }
    }
    return count;
}
```

Comment: Have a look at `stream()`, `flatMap()`, `filter()` and `count()`, e.g. `listRegistrationTypeWork.stream().flatMap(tab -> tab.getRegistrationTypeWorkAuthors().stream()).filter(author->author.getAuthorCoauthor().equals(type)).count()`. Using `CollectionUtils.isNotEmpty()` implies some of those lists might be null so you'd need to add some checks there, e.g. `filter(tab->tab.getRegistrationTypeWorkAuthors() != null)` before `flatMap()`.

Comment: What is the result of your attempts so far? Where exactly are you stuck?

Comment: Lambda expression: `(AuthorCoauthor type) -> {
int count = 0;
for(RegistrationTypeWork tab : listRegistrationTypeWork) {
if(CollectionUtils.isNotEmpty(tab.getRegistrationTypeWorkAuthors())) {
for(RegistrationTypeWorkAuthors author : tab.getRegistrationTypeWorkAuthors()) {
if(author.getAuthorCoauthor().equals(type))
count++;
}
}
}
return count;
}`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Although your statement is not clear enough on what *transforming to lambda expression* would mean, but I am assuming you would like to turn your imperative looping step to a functional *stream and lambda* based one.

This should be straightforward using:

- `filter` to filter out the unwanted values from both of your collections
- `flatMap` to flatten all inner collections into a single stream so that you can operate your `count` on it as a single source

```
public int qtyMaximumWorksByAuthorCoauthor(AuthorCoauthor type) {
    return listRegistrationTypeWork.stream()
            .filter(tab -> tab.getRegistrationTypeWorkAuthors() != null)
            .flatMap(tab -> tab.getRegistrationTypeWorkAuthors().stream())
            .filter(author -> type.equals(author.getAuthorCoauthor()))
            .count();
}
```

Answer (score 2):

In addition to Thomas fine comment I think you would want to write your stream something like this.

```
long count = listRegistrationTypeWork.stream()
  // to make sure no lists that are actual null are mapped.
  // map all RegistrationTypeWork into optionals of lists of RegistrationTypeWorkAuthors
  .map(registrationTypeWork -> Optional.ofNullable(registrationTypeWork.getRegistrationTypeWorkAuthors()))
  // this removes all empty Optionals from the stream
  .flatMap(Optional::stream)
  // this turns the stream of lists of RegistrationTypeWorkAuthors into a stream of plain RegistrationTypeWorkAuthors
  .flatMap(Collection::stream)
  // this filters out RegistrationTypeWorkAuthors which are of a different type
  .filter(registrationTypeWorkAuthors -> type.equals(registrationTypeWorkAuthors.getAuthorCoauthor()))
  .count();

// count returns a long so you either need to return a long in your method signature or cast the long to an integer.
 return (int) count;
```

Comment: Hi @Stephan Hogenboom The idea was great but my list is not Optional, it turns out it wasn't working, then I would have to make it Optional, but thanks for the contribution!

Comment: I was trying to compile in Java 8 then after googling found its Java 9 feature. This code worked for me. Thank you!!